# User Login Check from two table with only 4 columne name match and another on are different

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble making a login for normal users, I have two  tables, one is for admin users and the other for employees. The thing is that I want to use the same login and in the PHP first check if the username exists in the table admintable and if not check if it exits in empTable.but the filed name is different in both only field match that's username ,password, adn roll . Due to that reason unable to use Union operation .

Solved

```
<?php
                            if(isset($_POST['Login']))
                            {

                                $UserName=$_POST['UserName'];
                                $Password=$_POST['Password'];

                            $sql="SELECT * FROM userlogin  WHERE UserName= '".addslashes($UserName)."'and Password='".addslashes($Password)."'";

                            $login=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($login);
                            if($row['User_ID']>0)
                            {
                            $_SESSION['Admin_ID'] =$row['User_ID'];
                                    $_SESSION['roll']=$row['roll'];
                                    $_SESSION['UserName']=$row['UserName'];
                                    header('location:index.php');
                                    exit;

                            }

                            $sql="SELECT * FROM adminlogin  WHERE UserName= '".addslashes($UserName)."'and Password='".addslashes($Password)."'";
                            $login=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($login);


                            if($row['Admin_ID']>0)
                            {
                            $_SESSION['Admin_ID'] =$row['Admin_ID'];
                                    $_SESSION['roll']=$row['roll'];
                                    $_SESSION['UserName']=$row['UserName'];
                                    header('location:index.php');
                                    exit;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    echo"<div class='alert alert-error' align='center'><h4 style='color:red;'>Please Enter valid user name and password?</h4></div> ";
                                    echo'<meta content="1;login.php" http-equiv="refresh" />';
                            }

                            }
                            if(!empty($_SESSION['UserName']))
                            {
                            header('location: index.php');
                            exit;

                            }

                        ?>
```

Comment: Your code insertion did not work.

Comment: @JohnConde Where do you see that? lol (signal) - message disappeared. Goblins?

Comment: i am creating admin panel in these i got that trouble

Comment: You wrote *"Here is my code:"* - Where is your code?

Comment: Glad it got solved, *cheers*

Comment: Sorry for cheat ur code

Comment: My code? lol from where?

Comment: means your above text not ur code u can see my code its working

Answer (score 0):

"select *" but from where? if(1), why bother using a forced true block? Are you not forcing usernames to lowercase letters to keep uniqueness? You said two tables but you're referencing only one. Are you confident in addslashes as your security?

Edit: I see your revision. If that works great.